# EventFilter no reponde

Tags: python, python-3.x, eventos, pyqt

Estoy tratando de aplicar un `eventFilter` en un  `QFrame` sin embargo no hace nada la funcion `eventFilter`.

La intención es que al presionar el boton izquierdo del mouse sobre el frame(`FCliente`) muestre un simple mensaje pero no hace nada.

Este es mi codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import uic


class InstallerClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("AllSource/source/files_ui/installer_ui/InstallerPage.ui",self)

        #Efectos de Venatana
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        #Filtros de Eventos
        self.FCliente.installEventFilter(self)
        self.FCliente.setMouseTracking(True)

        def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
            if self.FCliente == obj:
                if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                        print("ok")
            else:
                print("none")
            return super(InstallerClass,self).eventFilter(obj,event)




app = QApplication([])
ic = InstallerClass()
ic.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Archivo.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>750</width>
    <height>450</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background:#0C2840;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>761</width>
      <height>371</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background:#1C435F;
background:#12314B;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>333</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>91</width>
       <height>31</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Lato</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:white;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Intalación</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="FCliente">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>43</x>
       <y>92</y>
       <width>171</width>
       <height>191</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background:red;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>165</y>
        <width>171</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Lato</family>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">color:grey;
</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Instalar Cliente</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>60</x>
        <y>80</y>
        <width>47</width>
        <height>13</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>128</width>
        <height>118</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="pixmap">
       <pixmap>../../Icons/pc.svg</pixmap>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="FServidor">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>293</x>
       <y>92</y>
       <width>171</width>
       <height>191</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true"/>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>165</y>
        <width>171</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Lato</family>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">color:grey;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Instalar Servidor</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>128</width>
        <height>118</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="pixmap">
       <pixmap>../../Icons/Server.svg</pixmap>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="FCancelar">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>543</x>
       <y>92</y>
       <width>171</width>
       <height>191</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true"/>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>165</y>
        <width>171</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Lato</family>
        <pointsize>8</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">color:grey;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Cancelar Instalación</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>20</y>
        <width>128</width>
        <height>118</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="pixmap">
       <pixmap>../../Icons/Remove.svg</pixmap>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>41</x>
      <y>9</y>
      <width>191</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>8</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color:#A0ABB2;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>School Administration System</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>5</y>
      <width>25</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap>../../Icons/Log.png</pixmap>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer error es simplemente de identación, defines tu método `eventfilter` dentro del `__init__`, por lo que al hacer:

```
self.FCliente.installEventFilter(self)
```

le instalas el filtro heredado de la clase padre, `QMainWindow`, que no hace lógicamente nada de lo que esperas.

El segundo problema es que `QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress` no tiene ningún método `key`, no es un evento de teclado. Lo que buscas es el método `butons()`:

```
if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
    if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        print("ok")
```

En definitiva, deberías tener algo así:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import uic


class InstallerClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("AllSource/source/files_ui/installer_ui/InstallerPage.ui",self)

        #Efectos de Ventana
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        #Filtros de Eventos
        self.FCliente.installEventFilter(self)
        self.FCliente.setMouseTracking(True)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.FCliente == obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    print("ok")
        else:
            print("none")
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```